# Why is the Updatepanel preventing my TextChanged event from firing?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, updatepanel

I have a very straightforward piece of code, but the TextChanged event will not fire. I've tried it without UpdateMode, ChildrenAsTriggers, and Triggers. And as you can see, I've tried it with. Still doesn't seem to fire.

Expectation: When I choose a date from the CalendarExtender, the TextChanged Event fires. Now I know that Page_Loads fires, when I do that. And I know it fires when I don't have UpdatePanel on my page.

I'm using Webforms ASP.NET 4.5, Visual Studio 2012.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Test.aspx.vb" Inherits="Test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Test.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <AjaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ajaxTSM1" runat="server">
        </AjaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <div>
            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="TestUP" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtDate" EventName="TextChanged" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>           
                <div>                   
                    <br/ /><br />
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding-right:20px;">Header1</td>
                            <td>Header2</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" ReadOnly="true" runat="server" Width="100px" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
                                 <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="ceDate" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDate" />
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
             </ContentTemplate>
             </asp:UpdatePanel>
         </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code Behind

```
Partial Class Test    
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page


    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        If Not IsPostBack Then
            txtDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString
        End If

        If IsPostBack Then

        End If
    End Sub


    Protected Sub txtDate_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtDate.TextChanged

        txtDate.Text = Request(txtDate.UniqueID)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in `Page_Load` to see if it is called? Try to remove the `If Not IsPostBack Then
            txtDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString
        End If`. On an asynchronous postback that property returns `false` (afaik), therefore you will overwrite the text which prevents the event from being triggered.

Comment: Try adding this to your Textbox markup: OnTextChanged="txtDate_TextChanged".

Comment: @NoAlias: Not required with the `Handles txtDate.TextChanged` in VB.NET.

Comment: Why are you changing txtDate's Text value inside the TextChanged event for that actual control ? And why are you doing it using the Request object ? Looks odd to me..

Comment: @sh1rts - I pulled that code from SO. If there's a better or correct way of doing it, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

I notice you have `ReadOnly="true"` specified for your TextBox.  I wouldn't expect any TextChanged events in this case.

See description of ReadOnly [in the MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.readonly%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)